# [codenameone]IOS Certificate generation failed

Tags: codenameone

Windows 11 Pro
Netbeans 12.3
Latest Simulator

Generation of IOS development certificate is producing an Error
Please see screen shot.

Also note some of the text is cut [image]
off in the dialog message.

Thoughts?

Best Regards

2 Apple Developers Certificate Pics
[image: Certificate Status]
[image: Profile Status]

Comment: We're looking into this

Comment: Did you try logging into your Apple developer account and make sure you don't have any agreements you have to "sign"?

Comment: Yes, Confirmed all development certs are valid.

Comment: Note: After getting the Error in the certificate generator in codenameone, all the developers certificated were set to invalid. I re-enabled all the certs in Apple acct to valid and repeated the process to confirm the error recurs. And it does.  Thoughts?

Comment: @MarkBolduc To clarify what Steve has said: you need to go to appstoreconnect.apple.com and make sure there are no user agreements or new license pages you need to accept there. Do the same for https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to say there are no user agreements or any other pending actions on my Apple Developers site. Have attached 2 pics from that site. Note: The error reported in the codenameone cert generator is cut off as I can't read the entire complaint.  Thoughts?

Comment: You should be able to scroll the error with the scroll wheel or by dragging it. I'll try to look on our side.